# How to make Django forms option Null

Tags: python, django, forms

I am trying to make a search refiner for my website and am having trouble setting up the form. On the index of my website there will be three refine options 'business_industry', 'business_region' and 'keywords'. The first two of these are choice fields and this is where my problem is. Because this is a search refiner each field is optional, however currently when the form is loaded the choice field is loading the first possible option. I want to load nothing and have a placeholder text such as "Choose a region"

[image: What it is doing at the moment]

My second problem follows on from this, from what I have gathered this form should be using the GET method and I am doing this. However when I submit the form data it is sending all of the fields to the URL even if they are blank, for example this picture shows how it is processing the keyword field even though it is blank, id prefer if it didn't send it, any ideas on how to solve this? Cheers!

[image]

Code -

Form -

```
class JobQuickSearchForm(forms.Form):
    business_address_region = forms.ChoiceField(JobListing.region_choice, widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'qs-form-input', 'default': ''}))
    business_industry = forms.ChoiceField(JobListing.industry_choice, widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'qs-form-input'}))
    keywords = forms.CharField(max_length=20, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'qs-form-input', 'placeholder': 'Enter Keywords...'}))
```

Choice Lists -

```
region_choice = (
    ('1', 'Auckland'),
    ('2', 'Wellington'),
    ('3', 'Christchurch')
)
suburb_choice = (
    ('1', 'Glendowie'),
    ('2', 'Kohimarama'),
    ('3', 'Herne Bay')
)
industry_choice = (
    ('1', 'Accounting'),
    ('2', 'Agriculture, fishing & forestry'),
    ('3', 'Automotive'),
    ('4', 'Banking, finance & insurance'),
    ('5', 'Construction & Architecture'),
    ('6', 'Customer service'),
)
employment_type_choice = (
    ('1', 'Full Time'),
    ('2', 'Part Time'),
    ('3', 'One-off'),
    ('4', 'Other')
)
```

View -

```
def index(request):

    print(request.method)
    if request.method == "GET":
        form = JobQuickSearchForm(request.GET)

    context_dict = {
        "form": form
    }

    return render(request, 'index.html', context_dict)
```

HTML -

```
  <div id="quicksearch">
    <h1 class="pageheader">Where would you to like to work?</h1>
      <form class="qs-form">
        {{ form.non_field_errors }}
        {{ form.business_industry }}
        {{ form.business_address_region }}
        {{ form.keywords }}<br>
        <button type="submit" class="qs-form-button">Search Jobs</button>
      </form>
  </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You probably want to add required = False to get null options available. For example:

```
business_address_region = forms.ChoiceField(required=False, JobListing.region_choice, widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'qs-form-input', 'default': ''}))
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/forms/fields/#required

Get requests encode the data in the URL, that's the expected behaviour. There shouldn't be a problem with sending blank data as long as the server side handles it properly. 
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp

Comment: Okay, good to hear about the URL concerns. Unfortunately using 'required' did not solve the other problem.

Comment: Try using an typed choice field with the empty value set.  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/forms/fields/#typedchoicefield
Or just set add an extra choice at the top with a value of None.